# ASP.NET MVC + Entity Framework - How to deal with DTO's and ViewModel's

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dto, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I'll try to describe a problem that I see very often in my workplace, but I couldn't find a way or a reasonable solution to it. I searched a lot about this and all I could find is what I already have implemented. The scenario is this:

I have an ASP.NET MVC app using Entity Framework which follows the Repository Pattern. I will use a simple Student/Teacher database structure to exemplify

**Entities**

```
public class Student : BaseEntity
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
  public Teacher Tutor { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher : BaseEntity
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class BaseEntity
{
  public byte State { get; set; }
  public Datetime CreateDate { get; set; }
  public Datetime UpdateDate { get; set; }
}
```

Now, let's say I need to expose a method to return a list of student names along with its teacher's name:

```
var students = context.Students.Include(x => x.Teacher).ToList();
```

The query above is bad and we all know it, since it returns all columns. Now, if we refactor to this:

```
var students = context.Students.Include(x => x.Teacher)
                               .Select(x => new 
                               {
                                   Name = x.Name,
                                   TeacherName = x.Teacher.Name
                               }).ToList();
```

I'll have a performant query that select only the fields I want. That's good. But now I need to make a choice. To return this list to my controller, I can either: Create a StudentDTO, or populate a Student instance with only the columns I selected in my query.

**DTO approach**

If I create a DTO and pass it along to my controller all will be "fine". No worries with extra unnecessary  fields.

**Return EF Entity Student**

If I return the database entity to my controller as is, even though I loaded it with only the fields I wanted I will get all the other empty fields. So I create a ViewModel to return only the data I want. *(This is what we are doing right now in most methods along with AutoMapper)*

**Problem:**

See the pattern? Either way I will ended up creating a class to map my return. I'm fine with this most of the time, but in the project I'm working right now, we have several methods to expose and each of them has a different return structure. For example, what if I wanted to return a list of students that contains only student Id and Name? Create another DTO or ViewModel?

The project has a team of 5 developers and the ViewModel folder is getting pretty stuffed with classes. I started instructing them to return an anonymous object inside a controller when a method return is very specific. I only create View Models now when I'm sure it can be re-used elsewhere.

But this anonymous approach had become also bad because now I have to do this in several controllers and I feel I'm repeating myself.

Is there any other approach I can use to solve this? Of course the project I'm talking about is much more complex than this example, with several entities and  pretty complex queries. I feel this happens a lot in other projects and I failed to find a decent way out of this.

Comment: Why is DTO approach with empty fields not ok?

Comment: With the DTO I will not have empty fields. I'll get empty fields if I return my Database Entity. See the base class? I don't need the State and other stuff in my client side. The problem is I find very inefficient to keep creating new classes (DTO or ViewModel) every time I need to return data in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

I wish I would have stumbled upon this question a year ago. Hopefully this info helps you or someone else even though its been awhile.

You are exactly right. You see a problem and your gut is already telling you there is an architecture problem and you are right.

I know it is a pain but the DTO approach is the correct architecture in my opinion.  These classes are a pain to create and use and we have all tried to shorcut around them at some point. But, you should be inheriting from base classes to share properties between objects to ease your pain. Also, use a 3rd party open source tool like automapper to move data easily between your data models and your dto objects.

Developers  make this architectural mistake all the time (trying to bypass the DTO object) especially if they are working on smaller software systems and not large corporate enterprise systems where the above architecture will fail fast while it may succeed forever in a small system.

**using your first example:**

```
var students = context.Students.Include(x => x.Teacher).ToList();
```

You would then copy students into a dto object (perhaps StudentDTO) and then pass this up to your UX and translate it into a viewmodel object. If Student and StudentDTO are identical then they can inherit from the same base class and StudentDTO gets created with about one line of code.

**Using your second example**

```
var students = context.Students.Include(x => x.Teacher)
                               .Select(x => new 
                               {
                                   Name = x.Name,
                                   TeacherName = x.Teacher.Name
                               }).ToList();
```

If you do not do this and instead translate everything into a ViewModel then you will end up with endless viewModels as you have.

However, even more importantly here, you shouldn't be able to move it into a viewmodel because ViewModels should sit in your UX layer and the fact that you can do this would indicate a small architecture issue on its own. ViewModels are only applicable to the UX and not anywhere else so keep them in the UX layer.

If you move your viewmodels into the UX you would find that you could not move your EF objects into your View Models and this would have steered you down the DTO architecture approach instead.

So why dont you just pass EF models up to the UX?

Well, you can. Works good in simple scenarios when you are just editing a single student for instance. This is tempting because its so easy to do and it works so why not do this?

For very simple, small systems please do. I think this is fine. you can pass an EF model up to the UX, translate it into a viewmodel and then the viewmodel back to the EF.  To do this your EF models should sit outside your data and ux layers in their own layer. I typically  use a dll called something like "MySoftwaremName.Common". I place all interfaces, data models and dtos in this layer and reference this layer from the UX, Service and Data layers so that DTOs and interfaces can easily be passed up and down the architecture.

My primary real world experience has shown that the primary reason you do not pass EF models directly up to the UX is Caching.

In small systems developers may not deal with this so this may work just fine. But in large systems where we are getting hit 50,000 to 100,000+ times a second caching is key.

What if you wanted to cache your student object so that it could be retrieved for the next 5 minutes without you hitting the db over and over again.

You cannot cache the EF models in ASP.NET or you will eventually encounter severe issues that are occuring randomly in your system that are hard to trace down.

You can stick the EF objects in Cache and even retrieve them from cache.   However, EF entities are attached to Database Context objects and that context eventually goes out of scope and gets garbage collected by .NET.  If you still have your Student object in cache after this happens and you retrieve it and try to use it  (using your own example again) to get the Teacher subclass "Student.Teacher"

you will get the yellow screen of death if that Teacher object is not eager loaded and is lazy loaded By EF. Ef will try to use the context to go fetch that Teacher and there isn't one and it will blow up.

To prevent all this it is best to move your EF objects into DTOs and then you can safely tranfer this data, cache it etc without any worry.

The only pain in this architecture comes in translating DTOs to viewmodels and EF models exactly as you have stated. But as I mentioned above, using proper base classes to share fields and using something like AutoMapper or another Mapping engine  will help you map quickly from DTOs to ViewModels and EF objects.

Comment: That's what I'm basically doing now.. but I moved away from EF to MongoDb. Well done answer.

Answer (score 0):

Always create a ViewModel.  The ViewModel is a UI concern.  your entity framework model is a domain concern.  ViewModels aren't about re-use.  They are about defining only what you need to satisfy the View that uses them.

Comment: This make sense, but doesn't quite answer my question. The real problem is that I'm creating a lot of ViewModels and finding this very inefficient. The way it is going, I'll have 100 files in less than months. Not very elegant.

Comment: you mentioned that you make a lot of small ViewModels like Id, Some value.  What about in those cases returning an IDictionary<Guid, string> as the model instead of defining a concrete model for every scenario.  That would eliminate all those Key, Value classes you are creating.

Comment: That was only an example. My real project, as I stated has in most of the cases complex queries and results. I don't have View models with less than 5 fields.

Comment: ViewModels should be 1:1 with your views. If you've got too many, think about ways to refactor your views and actions. See the bottom of this link on duplication which sums it up. https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2013/03/Why-You-Never-Expose-Your-Domain-Model-As-Your-MVC-Model/

Comment: Yes I get that. The problem is that most of my views are "composition" of several entities. It is quite hard to create a "catch all" view model. Also, there is several methods that are used for different things such as loading a select box for instance. I'll check the link either way, thank you!

Comment: If you have too many files, than there are 2 approaches to that. Put serveral vms into one file and start introducing inheritance. First vm has `id` and `name`. The extended vm then has the `BirthDate` property and so on. Of course this will add complexity.